# Laravel order by related table not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have this structure.

```
class Product extends Model{
    public function office()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Office::class,'office_id');
    }
}
```

I want to list `products` order by `office.name`.
this is the query

```
$res =  \App\Product::with(['office' => function($q){
        $q->orderBy('offices.name','asc');
    }])->get();
```

this is the output loop

```
    foreach($res as $key => $val){
        print "<br />user: ".$val->id.",  office: ".$val->office->id;
    }
```

this is the `Product` data:

`+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Life   |
| 2  | Cars   |
| 3  | Health |
| 4  | House  |
+----+--------+`

this is the data in `Office`

`+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | First office   |
| 2  | working office |
+----+----------------+`

The order by is not affecting the result.
same result, the order by like not existed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are simply "ordering" the offices by name, which means if each product had many offices, it would sort the offices alphabetically.

To sort (OrderBY()) a collection, the column has to be an attribute of the collection object. One solution could be to Join your models. SOmething like this might help you.

```
$res = Product::with('office')
->join('offices', 'products.office_id', '=', 'offices.id')
->select('products.*', 'offices.name')
->orderBy('office.name')
->get();
```

Comment: This is not the case, each product has one office. as the model says.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the case is, my code should still do the job. Give it a try. You can see I do `with('office')` how 'office' is singular right? because I know it has one office only.